# Do I need use remember only for a title in Scaffold?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm learning Compose, the following code is from the [article](https://howtodoandroid.com/jetpack-compose-scaffold-layout/#).

The author use  `var toolbarTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("Home") }` only for a title, is it necessary ?

I think `var toolbarTitle= mutableStateOf("Home")` is enough, right?

**Source Code**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetpackComposeScaffoldLayoutTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    var toolbarTitle by remember {
                        mutableStateOf("Home")
                    }
                    val scaffoldState =
                        rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed))
                    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
                        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                        topBar = {
                            AppToolbar(
                                scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                                scope = scope,
                                toolbarTitle = toolbarTitle
                            )
                        }, drawerContent = {
                            DrawerContent(scaffoldState = scaffoldState, scope = scope)
                        },
                       ...
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `remember` the value will reset again to `Home` on every recomposition by using `remember` the value will be persisted even after a recomposition

by the way recomposition means when the composable renders again which can happen a lot of times when something changes on the screen and needs to be rendered again

Answer (score 1):

I think, if the article is from a reputed source, the variable might have some further usage in the project. The very reason for initialising the variable as a `MutableState`is that the developer wants recompositions to occur upon the change of this value.

If this was not the case, it could have been just `var title = "Home"`, or better instead just use "Home" in the parameter, no need of a variable at all. You see, if you are creating a `MutableState`, in most scenarios, it is useless to declare it without using `remember`. In fact, the only scenario I can think of, to declare a `MutableState` without remeber is to trigger recompositions manually using the `var` as a trigger.

Anyway, most of the times, you want to read the value of the `var` that is declared `MutableState`. If any modifications are made to the value of the `var`, then a recomposition is triggered. Now, if you declare it without any `remember`ance, the value will be re-initlaised to whatever you provided as the initial value. The updated value is gone for good in this case.

Hence, in the latest versions of the compiler, I think it will not even allow you to create a `MutableState` var without using remember. If not a compile-time error, I'm sure it gives at least a warning (though I am almost certain it won't allow you to compile, which makes me think Compose Developers do not want us to trigger dummy recompositions!)

PS: The recompositions can be triggered manually by using `remember` too, so I guess that was not their motto.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change `toolbarTitle` later in your code you would have to use `remember { mutableStateOf("Home") }`

If it is always supposed to be "Home" you can just use `val toolbarTitle = "Home"` or use "Home" directly in `AppToolbar()`